# How to merge VDPROJ files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

we use SVN in a team work. in the solution there's a project for building MSI file called Setup. the project is indeed a vdproj file.
i've changed Setup.vdproj and found that someone else also changed it and committed the changes before me. so i've to Update, but the SVN itself can't merge them via Update properly (i think so, failure will happen, no?) and i myself can't merge it when it's shown in text mode. there're lots of numbers (GUIDs) there. so i need a visual way to merge my changes with others.
how can i do that?
what's ur idea?
thx

Comment: Yuck. You might want to consider moving away from vdproj in the long term. Particularly considering it doesn't exist in VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I would at least use the following properties:

```
svn:eol-style=native
svn:mime-type="application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

You might also want to require locking:

```
svn:needs-lock="*"
```